# How to user docker-compose to create my scrapy development environment in pycharm

Tags: mongodb, docker, scrapy, pycharm

I want develop my webcrawler using python3.6.3 scrapy mongodb and pycharm,
here is my project structure:
[image]

and here is my Dockerfile:
[image]

Here is my docker-compose.yml:
[image]

when i config my pycharm,some error message dispay like this:
[image]

What wrong with it and how to fix it? thanks a lot

Comment: you forgot to add your project :)

Answer (score 1):

Docker-compose versions are listed here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/

- I don't believe `"0.0.1"` is a valid docker-compose version. Try to use `"2"` or `"3"` instead
- There is a spelling error in your compose file (`build`)
- You're using a Python 3 image, and installing BeautifulSoup v3. You need to use a 4.x.x version for Python 3

Comment: thanks, I fix my docker-compose file version to "3" but it's still something wrong with it ,Could you like give some docker-compse.yml example to me?

Comment: @hl79-james can you edit your question & add the text files of your Dockerfile, requirements.txt, and your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @hl79-james when I run `docker build .` with a modified version of your docker code & requirements.txt I got two differenc error messages (It's unclear how the requirements.txt should be formatted from your reply below) Use 4 space left indent for each line to maintain line breaks and formatting. One error is basically that no version of the `request` package is found, the other is a failure in beautiful soup. This is really Python errors rather than Docker; I would mark this question answered and open up another with python label.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo on line 9.

`biuld` should be `build`